# How to create a Laravel polymorphic relationships where each type has a different level of multiplicity

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationship

Ok, so I'm trying to create a polymorphic relationship in Laravel that has four different types. The problem I have is that two of those levels are one-to-many and the other two are many-to-many. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Holiday extends AbstractModel {
  protected $table = 'holidays';

  protected $fillable = [
  'scope_id', 'scope_type', 'main_date', 'alt_date', 'comp_date', 'name', 'disabled'
  ];  

  public function scope() {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}

class Country extends AbstractModel {
  protected $table = 'countries';

  protected $fillable = ['name', 'iso_code', 'disabled'];

  public function holidays() {
    return $this->morphMany("App\holidays", "scope");
  }
}

class CountrySubdivision extends AbstractModel {
  protected $table = 'countries_subdivisions';

  protected $fillable = ['name', 'iso_code', 'countries_id', 'disabled'];  

  public function holidays() {
    return $this->morphMany("App\holidays", "scope");
  }
}
```

This is good for the first two levels which are one-to-many relationships. However, my problem lies in the last two levels which are many-to-many. Here are my models:

```
class Site extends AbstractModel {

  protected $fillable = ['name', 'code', 'division', 'absence', 'unpaid'];

  public function holidays() {
    return $this->morphToMany("App\Holiday", "scope");
  }
}

class Employee extends AbstractModel {

  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'code', 'division', 'absence', 'unpaid'
  ];

  public function holidays() {
    return $this->morphToMany("App\Holiday", "scope");
  }
}
```

The problem I have is when defining the inverse of the relationship. the `morphTo` method is used for one-to-many relationship. However, for many-to-many, I need to use the `morphedByMany()` method. however, I don't know how to use two different qualifiers for the same relationship.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that you need separate `morphedByMany()` relationships for `sites` and `employees` anyway.

Comment: Won't the `scope()` method interfere with the `morphByMany()` calls?

Comment: I don't see why. Did you try it?